# Changing axis() is not working to create a costume values

Tags: r, plot

everyone,

I am doing a density plot in R with plot().

```
plot(density(demo$GDP[demo$regime == "free"]), main= "Density Plot Free", xaxt="none")
axis(1,at=c(500,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000),labels=c("500", "1000", "2000", "3000", "4000", "5000"))
```

However, instead of creating the labels, it shows a 500 with 6 tiny lines at the beginning of the axis.

Any ideas of why this is the case? I've tried different forms of axis(), but I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `xlim=c(0,5000)` to your `plot()` command.

Remark: There is no need to specify `labels` in `axis()` if the labels coincide with your values for `at`, since by default (numerical) annotations are made at the tickmarks.